# Convert year/month to year/month/day in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column of data that looks like this.

```
200705
200706
200707
200808
```

I want to convert it to a column with year month and day. (2007/05/01).

The row in question was extracted from a csv file and defined as integers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a [question and answer site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Asking a programming question here would be more appropriate than just telling us what you want

Comment: In a csv file nothing is defined as integers, so did you already import the data in some specific container (list, numpy array, pandas dataframe...?) and if yes with which code? Is it possible that by `row` you mean `column`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `datetimes`, so use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) only:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m')
print (df)
        date
0 2007-05-01
1 2007-06-01
2 2007-07-01
3 2008-08-01
```

Also if data are read from file add parameter `parse_dates`:

```
temp=u"""date
200705
200706
200707
200808"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['date'])
print (df)
        date
0 2005-07-20
1 2006-07-20
2 2007-07-20
3 2008-08-20
```

But if need strings:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print (df)
         date
0  2007/05/01
1  2007/06/01
2  2007/07/01
3  2008/08/01
```

Or `f-string`s (python 3.6+):

```
df['date'] = [f'{x[:-2]}/{x[-2:]}/01' for x in df['date'].astype(str)]
print (df)
         date
0  2007/05/01
1  2007/06/01
2  2007/07/01
3  2008/08/01
```

Comment: Simple and effective sir :-)